# Possible to setUserInteractionEnabled value globally?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm working on a `spritekit` game, where most of the nodes/sprites handle user input(/touches) on their own. It would be neat to be able to do `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` in the gamescene to disable all these whenever I want to perform certain animations, however that particular solution doesn't work.

Is it possible to disable user input globally without changing the `userInteractionEnabled` setting in each individual sprite?

Comment: UIWindow* window = <....>; [window setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. Here is the code for that :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];// nested. set should be set during animations & transitions to ignore touch and other events
```

And for disable it you can use :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```